# Applying a CSS class to each <li> element by looping through it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a simple todo-list in Javascript and i am done adding elements. now i just want to add a simple CSS class to each li element inside unordered list. please guide me where i am wrong.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var input = document.getElementById('userinput');
var ul = document.getElementById("foo");
var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];



function inputLength(){
return input.value.length > 0
}

function createListElement(){

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value = "";

}

function addListAfterClick(){
if (inputLength()) {
    createListElement();
}
}

function addListAfterKeyPress(){
if (inputLength() && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
}
}

function taskDone(){
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i){
    items[i].classList.toggle("done")
 }
}

items.addEventListener("click", taskDone);

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeyPress);
```

```css
.done{
text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript and DOM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>No <span style="color: green">EXCUSES</span> do it must!</h1>
<input id="userinput" type="text" name="tasks" placeholder="Enter 
task">
<button id="button">Enter</button>

<ul id = "foo">
<li>Drink milk</li>
<li>Write some code</li>
<li>Eat healthy </li>
<li>Pray</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems right to me but the class is not applying with a click to `li` elements. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: items should be a list not a single element so you need to remove the `[0]` from: `var items = ul.getElementsByTagName("li")[0];` it should be `ul.getElementsByTagName("li")`

Comment: recheck the logic you have implemented, its throwing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you want to toggle each element on and off individually. The logic is this: get all the `li`s hardcoded into the `ul` on document load (achieved by doing `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", ...`), attach the click event to them one by one, and whenever a new item is added bind the click event to it as soon as it's created. The notable thing is that you bind events to individual DOM elements not entire classes, and subsequent added elements needed to be treated again. On a side note, this whole process can be simplified (a lot) by using the jQuery library.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');
var input = document.getElementById('userinput');
var ul = document.getElementById("foo");
var items;

function inputLength(){
return input.value.length > 0
}

function createListElement(){

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    li.addEventListener("click", taskDone);
    input.value = "";

}

function addListAfterClick(){
if (inputLength()) {
    createListElement();
}
}

function addListAfterKeyPress(){
if (inputLength() && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
}
}

function taskDone(e){
  e.target.classList.toggle("done");
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  for (let x of document.getElementsByTagName("li")) x.addEventListener("click", taskDone); 
});

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeyPress);
```

```css
.done{
text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript and DOM</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>No <span style="color: green">EXCUSES</span> do it must!</h1>
<input id="userinput" type="text" name="tasks" placeholder="Enter 
task">
<button id="button">Enter</button>

<ul id = "foo">
<li>Drink milk</li>
<li>Write some code</li>
<li>Eat healthy </li>
<li>Pray</li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In createListElement function add this code after created the li:
li.classList.add("done");